# Oracle REGEX to match two consecutive 'a'

Tags: oracle

I am trying to replace two consecutive `aa` in the oracle database using `REGEXP_REPLACE`.

The SQL I tried so far is below

```
   select regexp_replace('aab','(a)(a)|(a)(a)','\1 \2 \3') from dual;
```

The expected result is `a ab` and the actual result is `a a b`.

Basically, I want `(a)(a)` to match with two consecutive `aa`.What is the regular expression I must use?

Please note I am using this particular SQL as a  workaround if there are more than three or more consecutive `a`

```
select regexp_replace('aaa','(a)(a)|(a)(a)','\1 \2 \3') from dual;
```

gives me the result  `a a a` which is expected.

Comment: So why can't you just replace `aa` with `a a`?

Comment: Why not just `(a)(a)` and replace with `\1 \2`

Comment: There is a problem here, the second alternative never matches. `\3` is always an empty string, so you simply replace `aa` with `a a` and a space.  Please provide a real life example, not this oversimplified test case.

Comment: hi all i added a note why i can't use aa wth a a and (a)(a) with \1 \2

Comment: Wiktor i want to replace in a word with two consecutive 'aa' as 'a a' and it breaks if there are more than 3 'aaa'.i can do a double replace but i want to achieve the same in single replace to experiment the capability of REGEX

Comment: I think you'll be looking at a nested `REPLACE()` function to deal with `aa` twice to find all occurences. If lookahead is not supported I don't think you can do this with a single regex in Oracle.

Comment: Please refrain from changing the original intention of the question via Edit

Comment: @psaraj12 that being said. The answer in fact should be: It's not possible through a single regex in Oracle due to the absense of lookahead. The accepted answer below gives you the best option possible. Shame it's downvoted by the same user.

Comment: @jvdv i also feel the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need (slow) regular expressions, you can use the simple (faster) string function `REPLACE`:

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(value, 'aa', 'a a'), 'aa', 'a a') AS output
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS 
SELECT 'aab' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'aaa' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'abb' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'aabaa' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'aaaaa' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | Output |
> | --- |
> | a ab |
> | a a a |
> | abb |
> | a aba a |
> | a a a a a |

*SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0616a/2)*